# how to make the image resize based on browser size?

Tags: html, css

Here's my html

```
<div class="parent" >
  <div class="Home">
      <a href="home.php"><img id="homeinactive" class="homeIconInactive" src="images/navHeader/homeinactiveOver.png"/></a> 
  </div>
</div>
```

here's my css

```
.parent {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}


    img#homeIconInactive:hover{
      content: url("/images/navHeader/homeIconInactive.png") no-repeat;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 2;
      top: 0.3.8%;
      left:  49.2%;
      width: 55px;
      height: 50px;

    }

.containerHome img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

it was coded like that because the whole page is just an image embedded to an html to be shown as prototype, only the button on top has the hyperlink..the problem is, whenever I manually resize the browser, the button does not follow the size of the browser, is there a work around for this ?

Comment: First remove blank space from image src. You have given space just after `navHeader` in html

Comment: that's in stackoverflow pasting....not the issue

Comment: Can you create a fiddle or something so show actual behavior? another thing please try to elaborate more if possible. Thanks

Comment: just imagine you have pag design, and embedded it in a simple html. so it's like a whole image that looks like a web page. only the button on top of the page appears to be dynamic for having an anchor tag. when you resize your browser, the whole page image also follow the browser size except for the button alone

Comment: Does this answer your question? [fit background image to browser width and expand height if necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56677156/fit-background-image-to-browser-width-and-expand-height-if-necessary)

Answer (score 0):

Your `.containerHome` in your CSS isn't targeting anything based on the HTML you provided.

Change it to the following should work

```
.Home img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to make img width as 100%. it can automatically adjust it according to design.

also the width or parent is also required. because the image 100% width is representing the width of parent div.
as

```
.home{width:set width of parent; overflow:hidden}
.home img{width:100%} or .home .homeIconInactive{width:100%}
```